# How to access the device contacts list on Android using Unity c#

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, contact-list

Is it possible to access an Android phone's contact list using Unity c#?

The idea being that, inside our app, we can view the phone contacts and then add them one at a time into the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You have to create a plugin for connecting the android native functions to c# in order to get the contacts and their information. Here ([Contact list plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20885)) a example of a plugin which do that behaviour. It is a little slow, but you can create your own plugin with this manual ([Building plugins for Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)). I hope this helps you.